# Issue on Calling a Custom Method Targeting DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why it is not working

```js
  function changeColor(item){
   var item =  $(this);
   item.css("color", "green");
 }

$(".changer").on("click", function(){
     $('p').changeColor();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p >Name</p>
<button class="btn btn-default changer" type="submit">Changer</button>'
```

Comment: `.changeColor` s not a jQuery method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `changeColor` as **jQuery plugin** not as simple function .

```
 $.fn.changeColor=function(){
  
       this.css("color", "green");
 }
```

Then , no need  anymore for `item` argument since you could access to target element in jQuery via `this`;

__

## DEMO :

```js
$.fn.changeColor=function(){
           this.css("color", "green");
}

    $(".changer").on("click", function(){
         $('p').changeColor();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p >Name</p>
    <button class="btn btn-default changer" type="submit">Changer</button>'
```

Comment: FYI: `this` is already going to be a jQuery object, there is no need to wrap it

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function changeColor as if it was a jQuery plugin, but it is just a simple javascript funciton.

```
$.fn.changeColor = function changeColor(){
   var item =  $(this);
   item.css("color", "green");
 }

$(".changer").on("click", function(){
     $('p').changeColor();
});
```

See demo https://jsbin.com/cisujixiru/edit?js,output

Comment: You repeat same answer of @Abdennour , . To avoid vote-down , delete your answer, or give another solution